When I click it splits the window
I was setting up materials, I bumped my mouse and now whenever I click on any space in any window it creates a line. If I let go it splits the window.
Right clicking cancels it but its not letting me pull on node connectors because it keeps splitting the window instead. It even does it in the Edit Preferences menu. I couldn't find anything in the preferences or anything online about this problem.
Line preventing me to drag node points


go to your preferences

under keymap search for split(1) and check under split area (2) whether there is accidentally not ActionZoneArea (3) but maybe left mouse click? repair it just by pressing "restore" or you load factory settings.

Thank you. there is so much I still don't know. I have know clue what caused it to change to left mouse button but I know how to fix now. Thank you again..

@ShyDieonyx if the answer is correct, please mark it as such
